# Trying to assign an object to an object of different type in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of this code:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A(int x = 0): a(x) {cout << "A-ctor" << endl;}
    ~A() {cout << "A-dtor" << endl;}
};

class B {
public:
    int b;
    B(int x = 0): b(x) {cout << "B-ctor" << endl;}
    ~B() {cout << "B-dtor" << endl;}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a = b.b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
A-ctor
B-ctor
A-ctor
A-dtor
B-dtor
A-dtor
```

My question is, in this line in `main()`: `a = b.b`, an instance of class A is created and immediately destroyed. Why is this happening? Moreover, shouldn't I get a compilation error when trying to assign an object of one class to a different class?

Comment: You can mark `A:A(int)` as `explicit` to prohibit the implicit conversion from `int` to `A`.

Comment: It is the same as `A a; int x = 0; a = x;`. Are you expecting that to also not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assignment

```
a = b.b;
```

works, because there is a user defined (implicit) conversion from `int` to `A` via this constructor:

```
A(int x = 0): a(x) {cout << "A-ctor" << endl;}
```

Such constructors are called [converting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) (can be called with single argument and is not declared `explicit`). If you want to prevent the implicit conversion declare it as `exlicit`.

Output comes from

```
A a;            // A-ctor
B b;            // B-ctor
a = b.b;        // A-ctor
```

Note that the last line actually calls the compiler generated `A::operator=(const A&)`, because you did not declare a `A::operator=(int)`. A temporary `A` is created via the above constructor.

... and then desctructors as usual in reverse order of construction.

Comment: It might also be helpful to note that there is a compiler-generated `A::operator=(A const&)`, but no user-defined `A::operator=(int)`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Nevermind, missed the destructor.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Basically if any of the other four special members are user-declared, move assignment isn't implicitly declared : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes thanks, I am so much used to rule of 0 that one or two already confuses me ;)

Answer (score 2):

The value `a` can be assigned from an `A`. `b.b` can be converted to an `A`:

`b.b` is a int, and A has a constructor with an `int` argument, so it is used as converting constructor. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

Then, the newly created `A` is copied to `a` using it's default `operator=`, and then the `A(b.b)` it is destroued as it is not needed anymore.